# Can not load Office Addin in Word online when set Requirement Set in manifest file

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, word-addins

I load office add-in js file from CDN with this link: https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js

As document said this is the latest version of the office api. In my add-in, I only use `Office.context.document.setSelectedDataAsync` which is belong to `Selection Requirements Set` to replace value from my Word

I configure the manifest file with this code

```
<Requirements>
   <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="Selection" MinVersion="1.1"/>
   </Sets>
   <Methods>
      <Method Name="Document.setSelectedDataAsync"/>
   </Methods>
</Requirements>
```

When I publish the manifest file in Office 365, the add-in does not appear in the Admin Managed Tab (I'm testing in Word online and Word 2016)
[image]

I've tried to remove Methods Tag but the add-in still not show up. When I remove the `Requirements` tag, the add-in shows up again.

What I've done wrong here? Does I use wrong version of Office Api or the config in manifest is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extraction process needs to tag it for Office Online for Word and it doesn't appear to be happening properly. I will need to follow up on this

Comment: Smail MSTF Thank you for your support :D.

Comment: We have since made some changes. can you try again?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not trying to restrict where your add-in shows up, then consider not using the requirement set definition in the manifest.

Have you tried using the "Upload My Add-in" link (top right in the dialog shown) to upload your manifest and verify that it works? If that works, then perhaps there's an issue in how the manifest was published to Office 365?

Thanks!

Comment: My add-in worked on my debug but when i publish thee add-in in Office 365. It not appear in in the home screen and in 'My Add-ins' tab. so everytime user (in my organisation) use this add-in, they have to go to insert the add-in again.
That's why i consider to use the requirement set